# Regexp for accept numbers, letters and special characters

Tags: javascript

NKA-198, HM-1-0022, SCIDG 133

want regexp for the above codes. How can I Accept these codes and assign it to a variable??

Please suggest me and Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried any code yet?

Comment: so you want to accept numbers, letters and special characters. So what don't you want to accept? what's the intent of doing a regex? `/[\w -, ]/` will match what you have but I'm guessing there is an actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you have a solid understanding of the general structure of the strings you want to match - e.g., which separator symbols will be permissible (your example suggests `-`, `SPC`, but what about `+`? Would you want to match `NKA 198`, `SCIDG-133` too ?

As a base for further refinement, use the following code fragment:

```
var orig = "some string containing ids like 'NKA-198' and 'SCIDG 133'";
var first_id = orig.replace(/^.*?([A-Z]+([ -][0-9]+)+).*/, "$1");
var last_id = orig.replace(/(?:.*[^A-Z]|^)([A-Z]+([ -][0-9]+)+).*/, "$1");
```

***Explanation***

- core( `([A-Z]+([ -][0-9]+)+)` )

  Match any sequence of capital letters followed by a digit sequence preceded by a single hyphen or space character. The sequence 'space or hyphen plus number' may repeat arbitrarily often but at least once. This specification may be too restrictive or too lax which is the reason why you have to look up / guess general rules that the Ids you wish to match obey. In a strict sense, the regex you've been asking for is `^(NKA-198|HM-1-0022| SCIDG 133)$`, which most certainly is not what you need.

  The outermost parentheses define the match as the first capture group, allowing to reference the matched content as `$1` in the `replace method`. Using `replace` also mandates that your regexp needs to match the *whole* original string.
- additional parts / first regexp

  Matches anything non-greedily, starting at the string's beginning. The non-greedy operator (`.*?`) makes sure that the shortest possible match is found that still allows a match of the complete pattern (See what happens if you drop the question mark). Ths you'll end up with the first matching id in `first_id`.
- additional parts / second regexp

  Matches greedily (= as much as possible) until an identifier pattern matches. Thus you'll end up with the last match. the negated  character class (`[^A-Z]`) is necessary, since you there is no further information about the structure of the IDs in question, specifically which/how many leading capital characters there are. The class makes sure that the last character beforethe beginning of the matched id is not a capital character. The `^` in the  alternation caters for the special case that `orig` starts with a matchable ID - in this case, the negated char class would not match, because there is no 'last prefix character' before the match.

***References***

A more detailed (and more competent) explanation of regexp pattern and usage can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) provides info on regular expression usage in javascript.